# Removing duplicate pair in Pig

Tags: apache-pig

I am having the below sample

**Update:**

```
OBR|1|METABOLIC PANEL
OBX|1|Glucose
OBX|2|BUN
OBX|3|CREATININE
OBR|2|RFLX TO VERIFICATION
OBX|1|EGFR
OBX|2|SODIUM
OBR|3|AMBIGUOUS DEFAULT
OBX|1|POTASSIUM
```

In this sample consider all the **OBR** as one Test and every **OBR** is followed by **OBX** which is the result of the **OBR**. Every **OBR** is followd by id (such as 1,2 and 3 in this case) all the **OBX** of a particular OBR starts with 1. SO what i was thing is if i found one **OBR** i'll create one unique id and put it in all the **OBX** followed by the **OBR** untill i reach the **OBR** with id 2 again i'll do the same.
Below is my expected output.

**Expected Result :**

```
OBR|1|METABOLIC PANEL|OBR_filename_1
OBX|1|Glucose|OBR_filename_1
OBX|2|BUN|OBR_filename_1
OBX|3|CREATININE|OBR_filename_1
OBR|2|RFLX TO VERIFICATION|OBR_filename_2
OBX|1|EGFR|OBR_filename_2
OBX|2|SODIUM|OBR_filename_2
OBR|3|AMBIGUOUS DEFAULT|OBR_filename_3
OBX|1|POTASSIUM|OBR_filename_3
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [DISTINCT](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.7.0/piglatin_ref2.html#DISTINCT).Assuming you have relation A with duplicate records.The below statement will remove duplicate records and store the unique records in relation B

```
B = DISTINCT A;
```

Comment: Please help me i am struggling a lot in this.

Comment: Distinct didn't work?Your expected result doesn't involve all the unique records.

Comment: no distinct didn't worked. Yes it doesn't have all the unique records. i only want those records that i showed. How can i achieve this.

Comment: In that case you can't because there is no criteria the distinguishes those records.

Comment: can i do this using UDF's ?

Comment: If you can define the criteria of which record should make it to the final result,then you can do it.First define the criteria so that it can be selected.

Comment: ok i'll create it and then show you. please help me with it as i have to do it.

Comment: UDF will not help.Why can't you define the criteria?What makes those records unique?

Comment: ok i'll update my question. so that you can understand it well.

Comment: please check the question and give some response.

Comment: I don't know,hopefully other experts can provide you a solution

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this, it looks like a HL file. you can use Stitch, Over & Lead and come up with something like this. Probably there might be a better solution than this from a performance standpoint. But this should work I guess, please let me know how it goes.

```
DEFINE Over org.apache.pig.piggybank.evaluation.Over('long');
DEFINE Stitch org.apache.pig.piggybank.evaluation.Stitch;
DEFINE lead org.apache.pig.piggybank.evaluation.Lead;

in = LOAD 'hl_file' using PigStorage('|') as (id:chararray, num:int, reason:chararray);
temp = rank in;
ranked = foreach temp generate $0 as row_no, $1 as id:chararray, $2 as orig_id:int, $3 as reason:chararray;
OBR_data = FILTER ranked by id == 'OBR';
next_row_num_OBR = FOREACH (group OBR_data by id) {
sorted = ORDER OBR_data by row_no;
stitched = Stitch(sorted, Over(sorted.row_no, 'lead',0,1,1,(long)9999));
generate flatten(group) as (id:chararray), 
flatten(stitched.(row_no, orig_id, reason, result)) as (row_no:long, orig_id:int, reason:chararray, next_row_no:long);
}
OBX_data = FILTER ranked by id == 'OBX';
Crossed = CROSS next_row_num_OBR, OBX_data;
result = FILTER Crossed BY (OBX_data::row_no > next_row_num_OBR::row_no and OBX_data::row_no < next_row_num_OBR::next_row_no);
```

This should produce something like this:

```
(OBR,5,2,RFLX TO VERIFICATION,8,7,OBX,2,SODIUM)

(OBR,1,1,METABOLIC PANEL,5,2,OBX,1,Glucose)

(OBR,5,2,RFLX TO VERIFICATION,8,6,OBX,1,EGFR)

(OBR,8,3,AMBIGUOUS DEFAULT,9999,9,OBX,1,POTASSIUM)

(OBR,1,1,METABOLIC PANEL,5,3,OBX,2,BUN)

(OBR,1,1,METABOLIC PANEL,5,4,OBX,3,CREATININE)
```

Instead of file name or a constant, it just adds the OBR record to its corresponding OBXs.

Comment: you certainly provide one great method but i expect the output as i have mentioned in my question. For your different approach i am really grateful to you. I upvoted your answer. please upvote my question.